# How to trigger modal when input type is submit

Tags: html, ajax, asp.net-mvc, modal-dialog

I want to trigger modal when input type is submit,
when I complete my require , need to submit data then launch the modal sample
(which is using ajax to update zone) 
but I tried to add data-toggle on input type,
after adding it, the form seems like it can't be post to Controller , 
does anybody have any solution on it?

```
<input type="submit" value="Ok" />
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data- 
target="#exampleModalCenter">
    launch modal
    </button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Your Content</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" id="PlanCompleteZone">
                    @Html.Action("PlanComplete")
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recomend you that use a listener for onSubmit event in the form so you can trigger a javascript function on submit and in that function you must prevent the event(submit) and launch your modal and finally use an ajax request to submit the form content.

```
<form method="POST" onsubmit="submit(event);">
    <input type="submit" value="Ok" />
</form>
   <script>
        function submit(event){
           event.preventDefault();
           //assuming bootstrap 3
           $('#exampleModalCenter').modal('show')
           //ajax request
        }
   </script>
```